# Python 2.7 File Container containing HTML XML JPG PNG PDF with f.readlines()

Tags: python, html, pdf, containers

Okay I got a file container that is a product of a Webcrawler containing a lot of different file types, likely but not all are HTML XML JPG PNG PDF. Most of the container is HTML text so I tried to open it with:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
```

which basically fails when I hit a PDF. The files are structured in a way so that every file is preceded by a little meta Information telling me what kind of file type is following.
 Is there a similar method to `.readlines()` in python to read files line by line. I don't need the PDFs I will Ignore them anyway I just want to skip them.

Thanks in advance

Edit: 
Example File: [GDrive Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwukDl7gHHdBeWNtcWRucXdGQ3c/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please use open as following `open(fname,'r')` EDIT: Ignore. As @brunodesthuilliers noted it is the default.

Comment: @hassaan_w: 'r' is the default when opening a file.

Comment: Example File: [GDrive Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwukDl7gHHdBeWNtcWRucXdGQ3c/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found a solution just open the container with `open(fname,'rb')` and you are able to parse it line by line

Answer (score 0):

`file` has a `readline()` method too, but the idiomatic way is to simply iterate over the file:

```
with open("/works/even/with/a/pdf/document.pdf") as f:
    for line in f:
        do_something_with(line)
```

Also I don't understand what you mean by "(it) basically fails when I hit a PDF". I have no problem applying the above code to a pdf file here.

Comment: The Container is constructed in the following way: lines 0-100 HTML; 101-189 HTML; 190-689 PDF; 690-750 HTML; 751-1500 PDF ... and so on so as soon as I arrive at a line that is part of a PDF the open process stopes (without any exceptions or anything) tried it which your suggestion to with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

For reading files line by line you could use [fileoperations](http://fileoperations.github.io/FileReader/).

```
from fileoperations import FileReader

print FileReader.LineByLine(fname) #Note this returns a list of lines.
```

Could you show us a sample of the pdf? This works for my PDF's.